# Inserting Array Values Into Div Boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the user when he/she clicks a button for a value from an array to be inserted into one of five div boxes. The code has no errors on firebug but when I click the button nothing happens. What's wrong with my code. Here is the jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/fHHnq/13/

Here is the relevant js code...

```
var news = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11",
        "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"];


$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.button').click(function() {

    var article_id = 1;

    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;

    $('.class_' + number).html('news[article_id]');

    article_id++;

 });

});
```

Comment: once fix hyphens above code won't work because of quotes around variable: `news[article_id]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're incorrectly assigning classes and your HTML uses `-`, but your JavaScript is using `_` for class names.

Here is the working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fHHnq/16/

Answer (score 0):

In your html you are using " class-1 " and in your javascript you are using  " $('.class_' + number)" which will result class_1. so there is mismatch in class-1 and class_1